# Issue setting instance variables

Tags: java, variables, parameters

I am passing some coordinates from one class to another using the following code

**edited to show more detail

At start of class1:

```
public class BattleGui implements ActionListener {
    private int xCoordinate;
    private int yCoordinate;

    public void coordinateHandler(int xCoord, int yCoord) {
        xCoordinate=xCoord;
        yCoordinate=yCoord;
        System.out.println("Coordinates Received "+xCoord + " " +yCoord);
        System.out.println("Test "+xCoordinate + " " +yCoordinate);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String classname = getClassName(e.getSource());
        JComponent component = (JComponent)(e.getSource());
        cellState cs = new cellState();
        if (classname.equals("JMenuItem")) {
            JMenuItem menusource = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
            String menutext  = menusource.getText();

            // Determine which menu option was chosen
            if (menutext.equals("Load Game")) {
                /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle Load Game **********/
                System.out.println(cs.turnFeedback());
                LoadGame();
            }
            else if (menutext.equals("Save Game")) {
                /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle Save Game **********/
                SaveGame();
            }
            else if (menutext.equals("New Game")) {
                /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle Save Game **********/
                NewGame();
            }
        }
        // Handle the event from the user clicking on a command button
        else if (classname.equals("JButton")) {
            JButton button = (JButton)(e.getSource());
            int bnum = Integer.parseInt(button.getActionCommand());
            int row = bnum / GRID_SIZE;
            int col = bnum % GRID_SIZE;
            //col=yCoord;
            //row=xCoord;
            //System.out.println(e.getSource()); 
            //System.out.println(bnum / GRID_SIZE);
            fireShot(row, col);


            if (row==xCoordinate){
                if (col==yCoordinate){
                    button.setBackground(cellColour[cs.turnFeedback()]);
                }
                else {
                //Remember to change the 1 to whatever is reported back from cell class cell state
                //button.setBackground(cellColour[cs.turnFeedback()]);
                button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
            else {
                button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }  
    }
```

From class2:

```
    public void shipDeploy() {
        int gridLength;
        int lengthDraw;        
        int winningNumbers = 0;
        int xCoord;
        int yCoord;

        xCoord=99;
        yCoord=100;
        System.out.println(xCoord + "\n" + yCoord);
        BattleGui bGui = new BattleGui();
        //Passing the coordinates back to the battlegui coordinate handler class
        bGui.coordinateHandler(xCoord, yCoord);
    }
```

This  passes these two values to a coordinate handler method within the first class.

within this class I have an xCoordinate variable used throughout a variety of methods, the problem is that I dont seem to be able to set this, 0 is always being returned outside of this method for xCoordinate and yCoordinate and I dont understand why, as they seem to be ok in the line `System.out.println("Test "+xCoordinate + " " +yCoordinate);` above.

Comment: You'll need to show more of the code, because there's nothing that looks immediately wrong here.

Comment: when i try to use xCoordinate or yCoordinate later in another method they are returned as 0 which i dont understand how :(

Comment: @RST As the first commenter said, you need to post more code. Chances are how you're assigning the variables are being affected by scope - but you're not showing us that code, so we can't tell.

Comment: My guess is you have variable name shadowing going on, but until we see the code, who knows.

Comment: Are you probably working with a language like C where parameters are by Ref?

Comment: btw, check out http://sscce.org/ and try to reduce your code to be absolute minimum that still shows the problem

Comment: thanks for the tip bohemian will check that out - ive made some further edits to show everything that reference this code, its a tad messy at the minute but should give an idea of the prob

Comment: @Raffaeu this is quite obviously Java.

Comment: Between your Class2 call to  bGui.coordinateHandler(xCoord, yCoord) and the moment when BattleGui.actionPerformed() is executed, do you create another instance of BattleGui ?

Comment: As your code reads at the moment, bgui is a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of shipDeploy.

Comment: @Eric R the actionPerformed is most likely reused every time the user clicks on a jbutton on the grid.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller the values are passed on to coordinateHandler() so its not confined locally.

Comment: @RST Yes, but bGui goes out of scope at the end of shipDeploy() and becomes a candidate for GC. Where is actionPerformed() being called?

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller just figured it out on my own, quite simple really, actionlistener was basically re-instantiating the variable on every "event" explaining the zero values, as soon as i took this process outside of the listener it worked and set the values as intended. thanks for the input guys and hope this helps someone along the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just figured it out on my own, quite simple really, actionlistener was basically re-instantiating the variable on every "event" explaining the zero values, as soon as i took this process outside of the listener it worked and set the values as intended. thanks for the input guys and hope this helps someone along the way!